# How to generate an opacity helper in sass

Tags: css, sass

I can't seem to generate an opacity helper classes with this code

```
@for $o from 1 through 9 {
    .o#{$o} {
        opacity: 0.#{$o};
    }
}
```

i think it has something to do with the value of the opacity `0.#{$o};`...

the code should generate:

```
.o10 { opacity: 0.1; }
.o20 { opacity: 0.1; }
...
.o90 { opacity: 0.9; }
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. Can you please improve your question and tell us what you get.

Comment: I'm just getting this error Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  Invalid CSS after "        opacity: 0": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ".#{$o};"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just divide by 10: `opacity: $o / 10;`.

```
@for $o from 1 through 9 {
    .o#{$o} {
        opacity: $o / 10;
    }
}
```

Sassmeister [demo](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/3cf938ad50b13b5b1b8c62b78ae4b0f3).

---

Opacity as string [example](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/1045b130503fed65d0f4c76fb997e30c): `opacity: unquote("0." + $o);`.